# Design new table structure, need idea

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In below table CUSIP, ISIN, SEDOL, LocalCode are being some unique identifiers corresponding to a company name.

```
table: description_master
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| CUSIP     | ISIN        | SEDOL | LocalCode | Description                         |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| 594918104 | US594918104 | 8S104 | MSFT      |Microsoft Corp                       |
| 369604103 | US369604103 | 4D103 | IBM       |International Business Machines Corp.|
| G8770Z106 | US08770Z106 | Z1062 | GE        |General Electric Co.                 |
| M40184208 | US040184208 | 42082 | TSLA      |Tesla, Inc.                          |
| G3827X105 | FR03827X105 | X1053 | AAPL      |Apple Inc.                           |
| 01069SFS8 | CA01069SFS8 | 9SFS8 | GOGL      |Golden Ocean Group                   |
| 57584X7C9 | IE57584X7C9 | 4X7C9 | TNC       |The Tennant Company                  |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Assuming there will be more tables like above with first 4 columns always being CUSIP, ISIN, SEDOL, LocalCode and then some extra column containing  other info.
let's name those table: table1, table2, table3.

now A user wants to have data from all these tables(description_master, table1, table2,table3). for **cusip 594918104, cusip 369604103, ISIN US040184208, Localcode GOGL, LocalCode TNC**

I want to design a table named "job_details" where I will store user requested inputs and JOIN this table with other tables that I already have, to get the requested data. something like below structure

```
table: job_details
+-------+---------------------+-------------------+
| job_id| requested_identifier| identifier_type   | 
+-------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 1     | 594918104           | CUSIP             |
| 1     | 369604103           | CUSIP             |
| 1     | US040184208         | ISIN              |
| 1     | GOGL                | LocalCode         |
| 1     | TNC                 | LocalCode         |
+-------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Since job_details totally being imaginary, its structure can be like anything.
e.g:

```
    +-------+-----------+------------ +-------------------+
    | job_id| CUSIP     | ISIN        | SEDOL | LocalCode |
    +-------+------------------------ +-------+-----------+
    | 1     | 594918104 | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      |
    | 1     | 369604103 | NULL        | NULL  | NULL      |
    | 1     | NULL      | US040184208 | NULL  | NULL      |
    | 1     | NULL      | NULL        | NULL  | GOGL      |
    | 1     | NULL      | NULL        | NULL  | TNC       |
    +-------+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

my two concerns are: 1) what should be the job_details table structure.
2) How to join job_details table to description_master table to get something like:

> select * from description_master INNER JOIN job_details ON job_id=1 AND (some other conditions)

the desired result:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| CUSIP     | ISIN        | SEDOL | LocalCode | Description                         |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| 594918104 | US594918104 | 8S104 | MSFT      |Microsoft Corp                       |
| 369604103 | US369604103 | 4D103 | IBM       |International Business Machines Corp.|
| M40184208 | US040184208 | 42082 | TSLA      |Tesla, Inc.                          |
| 01069SFS8 | CA01069SFS8 | 9SFS8 | GOGL      |Golden Ocean Group                   |
| 57584X7C9 | IE57584X7C9 | 4X7C9 | TNC       |The Tennant Company                  |
+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm lost at having multiple tables.  Why are there multiple tables?  That seems like a bad design choice.  Perhaps there are other approaches that don't involve so many tables.  In fact, it sounds like you just want a JSON column in the master table to store flexible attributes for each row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  hi thanks for reply.. tables are maintained by different vendor each one giving  specific data  for a cusip, isin, sedol, localcode combination. Hence I end up having many tables. this is why I m thinking of having JOINs on those tables with one my table (which will stored requested data info). also record maintain by new table will be used for future reference.

Comment: . . Why not just create a single view with all data from all the tables and let users use that view?  Or create separate views for each user?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I haven't worked with the views before. However I will definitely use in future. Currently, because of time constrain  and with all my knowledge of mysql (still a learner) all I can think of a solution to this problem is to have table. and join it with my existing table.

Comment: . . Tables that contains as *values* the names of columns are tables is just going to make your life difficult.  Very difficult.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree with you..column name as values in another table doesn't look good way to store it. May be the the 2nd job_details structure work?